# How to convert a data acquisition Matlab script to Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, data-acquisition

The Matlab script which I wrote is going to be used as a feedback for my control system. I have downloaded a library done called "Custom Arduino Library for HX711" by Nicholas Giacoboni.

I want to convert a Matlab script which I wrote [Matlab script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G24ap.png). I have also tested the script by itself and it works.
HX711 is a load cell amplifier ADC converter.

```
function data = Loadcell()
eml.extrinsic('arduino','addon','read_HX711')

a = arduino('COM5','Mega2560','libraries','ExampleAddon/HX711');
scale = -338000;
while 1
    LoadCell = addon(a, 'ExampleAddon/HX711',{'D6','D5'});
    data = (read_HX711(LoadCell)-7388092)/scale
    
end
end
```

the layout of simulink at the moment [Simulink function block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Dwi.png).

And I run Simulink on Normal mode and simulation stop time at inf it comes up with this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V60ps.png). How do I solve this error and get this working?

Regards,

Allan

Comment: Please provide both code and error as text, not as images. Also, inline the image in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum you need to define the size of `data` at the top of the file.  The parser has no idea of what `read_HX711` returns and hence cannot allocate memory for `data`.  You probably need to do the same for `a` and `LoadCell`.

That is, you need something like,

```
data = zeros(1,1);
a = zeros(1,1);
LoadCell = zeros(1,1);
```

at the top of the file.

If that doesn't work, then I would suggest that you put all of your above code into a function in a separate m-file, where that function returns just your `data` variable.  Then in your `MATLAB Function` block code just have one call to your new function (which will still need to be defined as extrinsic).

Comment: So, I have added:
 data = zeros(1,1);
a = zeros(1,1);
LoadCell = zeros(1,1);
and it gives the same error. So, I did the second method having one script for the data acquisition. And the Matlab function block code calling for it.
function Data = Loadcell() 
    eml.extrinsic('Loadcell');
  Data = Loadcell;
end
Sorry I'm new to this website and in programming.

Comment: Actually I solved it using your second way. Thank you very much.