# How to call M file to Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

I got a script from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000684/how-to-convert-a-data-acquisition-matlab-script-to-simulink) and it runs correctly in MATLAB. However, when I create a Simulink model, it runs normally, but I can get the data from m file.

MATLAB script:

```
function data = Loadcell()
    eml.extrinsic('arduino','addon','read_HX711')
    a = arduino('COM5','Mega2560','libraries','ExampleAddon/HX711');
    while 1
        LoadCell = addon(a, 'ExampleAddon/HX711',{'D2','D3'});
    data = read_HX711(LoadCell)
    end
end
```

Simulink function

```
function data = Loadcell()
    coder.extrinsic('Loadcell');
    Loadcell = zeros('double');
    data = zeros('double');
    data = Loadcell
end
```

I run Simulink in external mode using Arduino and I don't get the data from that code. How can I use that MATLAB script to use it in the Simulink block model and get the data?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a couple of issues

1. naming your Embedded MATLAB function in Simulink the same as the MATLAB function.  (How would you expect Simulink to know which function it's supposed to call?  The MATLAB function, or re-entering the Embedded MATLAB function?)
2. defining `Loadcell` as an `extrinsic` function, then (re)defining it to be a double `0.0`, then trying to execute it as a function.

I suspect you want something like,

```
function data = Loadcell_Wrapper()
    coder.extrinsic('Loadcell');
    data = zeros(1,1,'double');
    data = Loadcell()
end
```

(Also, not part of your question, but isn't there an infinite loop in the MATLAB code?)

Comment: Yes, when I called the .m file containing the MATLAB code in MATLAB there was an infinite loop in MATLAB, so I had to stop the script. And I think the script in MATLAB can run correctly.

Comment: But when I call it in simulink using the code I use, simulink can run but the data I see in the infinite loop in MATLAB does not occur in simulink

Comment: And I have tried the code that you have provided, but it gives an error

"The extrinsic function 'Loadcell' is not available for standalone code generation. It must be eliminated for stand-alone code to be generated. It could not be eliminated because its outputs appear to influence the calling function. Fix this error by not using 'Loadcell' or by ensuring that its outputs are unused."

Comment: Simulink stepping through time (with a simulation stop time of `inf`) is typically the equivalent to MATLAB having an infinite loop.  So you probably need to remove the infinitie loop, and I would assume you also only want to do the initialization (which I assume the `a = ...` line in the code is doing) only once (not at each time step).   I'd suggest looking at the doc for the `arduino` package to see how to call its functions from a Simulink model.